# Align graphic in minipage

Tags: graphics, formatting, vertical-alignment, minipage

I'm trying to align the content of two miniboxes. The left one contains an image, the right one a heading, a sub heading, a note and some explanation to it.

**I'd like the centre of the graphic to be at the same hight as a "virtual point" between the heading and the sub heading.**

I've tried now nearly everything which I could think of but nothing really worked well. Either it's entirely centred vertically within the minibox, above the header or at the point it is now. I also tried to understand the way LaTeX aligns the stuff with the fboxes but that didn't helped me either.

If anyone could help he, I'd be really happy :)

Currently it looks like this:

[image: Problem]

And here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}

%\fbox{
\begin{minipage}[t][][b]{0.08\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=1.2cm] {img/mail}
\end{minipage}%                    
%}
%\fbox{
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.84\linewidth}  
\noindent {\color{red}\bfseries\uppercase {Head}} 
\hfill {\color{red}\fontsize{10pt}{12pt}Note}
\par    
\noindent {\color{red}\textit{Subhead}} \par 
\noindent\hangindent=2em\hangafter=0 \small \blindtext % Description
\normalsize \par         
\end{minipage}   
%}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it something like this you want? I played with the parameters of  `\raisebox`:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\noindent\parbox[t]{0.15\linewidth}
{\raisebox{-0.7\height}{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth] {pepe-le-pew2}}}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.84\linewidth}
  \noindent {\color{red}\bfseries\uppercase {Head}}
  \hfill {\color{red}\fontsize{10pt}{12pt}Note}
  \par
  \noindent {\color{red}\textit{Subhead}} \par
  \noindent\hangindent=2em\hangafter=0 \small \blindtext % Description
  \normalsize \par
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

B.t.w., the `usenames` option for `xcolor` is deprecated: it's the default now.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\setlength{\parindent}{0in}
\begin{document}

\parbox{1.2cm}{%
\includegraphics[width=1.2cm]{example-image}
}
%
\parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-1.2cm}{\par% 
\noindent{\color{red}\textbf{\uppercase{Head}}}
\hfill {\fontsize{10pt}{12pt}\selectfont\color{red}Note} \par    
\noindent{\color{red}\textit{Subhead}} 
}

\addvspace{.7em}
\noindent\hangindent=\dimexpr2em+1.2cm\hangafter=0 \small \blindtext % Description
\normalsize \par          

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Well somehow yes but I need to maintain the rest of the structure

Comment: @FriendlyGuy  - What is the structure you want to maintain?

Comment: The way the head, subhead, note and the text are indented

Comment: You have to indent the paragraph text 1.2cm+2em. By the way, if you put the text in a minipage, it won't allow page breaks.